# how to make chromium/chrome only reloads the modifled files?

Tags: google-chrome

My site has a lot of img, js, css files. If one file is modified by developer its url will be changed too, otherwise the url will not be changed.
I wish chromium/chrome only reloads the modified files according to the url, but actually it often reloads all files with some unknown rules　without using cache.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a vague and broad question, but I guess you use different URLs to prevent retrieving old, cached versions of changed resources (that's one sure way anyway, although not necessarily the best way) and have a problem with Chromium-based browsers not caching resources that are unchanged.

Chromium respects caching directives as per spec, so it seems you're not sending the appropriate caching directives (headers) in the first place or have a problem testing the caching behavior (e.g. testing with caching disabled). Determine which is the problem and fix it.